# python list from string

Tags: python, json, list

problem is self explanatory:

```
import simplejson as json
a = u"[(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833), 'ACTIVE', [u'my.test.service', '{}'])]"
json.loads(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 384, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 418, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Question is obvious: How can I convert my string to a list?

Comment: Umm... I don't find the problem self explanatory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833) has no meaning in JSON.
Conversely, if you try to do the opposite, you'll notice the problem:

```
json.dumps([(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833), 'ACTIVE' [u'my.test.service', '{}'])])

TypeError: datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833) is not JSON serializable
```

**Edit**:

Actually, reading your question again made me notice you did not specify you wanted to use JSON, just "convert the string to a list". Not sure what your use case is, but this will work in your case:

```
In [23]: a = "[(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833), 'ACTIVE', [u'my.test.service', '{}'])]"
In [24]: eval(a)
Out[24]: [(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833), 'ACTIVE', [u'my.test.service', '{}'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a function inside of your code. You need to break the datetime() out of your JSON stream, or put it into the right format. Try parsing known JSON code first.

Answer (score -1):

The first character when you're assigning a is a 'u' but with no quotes.  Try removing that and see how it goes, like this:

```
import simplejson as json
a = "[(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 14, 50, 13, 996833), 'ACTIVE', [u'my.test.service', '{}'])]"
json.loads(a)
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Also try `type(u"string")`.